# Searching for imagery on Planet API: "jq command not found"

Tags: installation

I've been trying to follow the [Planet API docs](https://www.planet.com/docs/api-quickstart-examples/step-1-search/#item-types) to search for imagery. Specifically, when I try to make the first API call using the following code,

```
curl -L -H "Authorization: api-key $PL_API_KEY" \
'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types' | jq '.item_types[].id'
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: jq: command not found
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   291  100   291    0     0    757      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   759
100  3034    0  3034    0     0   6552      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  6552
(23) Failed writing body
```

I understand this is probably an issue with jq, but I can't figure out why. I have double checked that all necessary packages are installed, including jq. I have also run `echo $PL_API_KEY` and it returns my API key as expected. Running the command with sudo does not help either. It may be worth mentioning that I installed `jq` with `npm` as opposed to `pip` because running `pip install jq` did not work for me due to build errors.
Any help?

Comment: You haven't installed `jq`.  It isn't available from `npm`. You may have installed `jq.node` or `jq2` which have CLIs called `jqn` and `jq2`.  They are different to `jq` though.  If using Linux, just install it from your package manager (i.e. for Debian/Ubuntu based Linux - `sudo apt install jq`), for MacOS see https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: Note that `jq` is not part of the Planet API, nor is it geospatial software. It's purely a command line JSON tool.